# Show students in particular standard in school + Rails

Tags: ruby, activerecord, devise, ruby-on-rails-5, erb

I have two different models one is "Standard" which has only a standard named attribute and a "Student" model which is inherited from user model which has standard attribute also .
so here i want to show students on standard show page where Standard's->standard is == Student->standard,where 'standard' in students attribute is and part of serialise attribute which is named 'custom_attr' is an array

**Edit**

i have tried this in 'standard helper'

```
module StandardsHelper    
  def students_list
    User.where(role: "student")
  end
end
```

and tried in 'standards show'

```
<% if @standard.class_room %>
   <%= render 'users/students', users: students_list %>
<% end %>
```

here i created a partial file thats why i need to find users with role student in standard helper...
but it is showing all students in one standard only,such as when i click on 12th standard it showing all students and when i click on 11th standard it is not showing any record...

thank you in advance for any help and advice....

**Update**
I just want to show students when i click on 11th class then how will i extract students who are in 11th class from user database...

sorry , i know that my question is bit confusing so that's why i edited this... please help me for clear my confusion ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this?

```
User.where(role: "student").select{|user| user.custom_attr['standard'] == '11th'}
```

I hope this will help you

Comment: i was trying it as User.where(role: "student").select{|user| user.custom_attr.first["standard"] == @standard.class_room} to compare when user click on different standards, and it is working , thank you @AmolMohite sir it  will made my day... :-)